# Firefox insists that the table display style is "block" when it's not

Tags: asp.net, css, firefox

I have a table, it looks wrong, so I inspect the element and see that the inline style display = "block".  So I go to the HTML, and the inline style doesn't say display: block, it doesn't have anything defined for display.  I put an inline style "display: table" and refresh the page, and the inspect element utility still says that it's "display: block".  If I inspect the element, it says "display: block", but if I right-click on the page and go "view page source", I see the inline style saying "display: table".

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Some JavaScript code is changing it!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Is ir only Firefox? Did you try other browsers? If you see an inline style in view source (rather than the console/firebug), it is most likely the in the HTML itself when the browser received it (as against manipulated by javascript *after* the browser received it).

Comment: I'd be very interested in the source here.

Comment: This is only happening in Firefox.  IE is fine with the page.  What's really weird about the Firefox behavior, is the part where inspecting the element shows "display: block;", but viewing the page source shows "display: table".  The behavior is completely consistent with bfavaretto's response, the web console will respond "block" if I type in document.getElementById("tbResults").style.display, and it will change to what it should be if I set the value throught the console. but I haven't yet been able to find the javascript that's changing it.  there has to be a script that I haven't seen

Comment: One more thing on this that's weird.  It's an asp.net page.  The table display's correctly when you first get there, event though in the console, and in "inspect element", it shows display = "block".  It's when you go to page 2 in the table, you get the bad display.  Does anybody know of scripts that asp.net inserts without telling you?

Comment: Okay, I found the script.  I'm an idiot.  It's a script written by me too.  Thank you all for your patience. Favoretto had it.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and solved it while your post was still on my screen, so I figured I'd answer:
If the element's positioning is set to absolute, firefox will convert table-cell to block.
By setting it to relative, things came out the way they should.